# X axis tick not centering on column series in highcharts (jsFiddle)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Stack,

For some reason highcharts seems to not want to place x axis ticks centered underneath stacked column charts when the chart is a DateTime type chart.

As you can see in this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4Mngx/2/ and you can also look that this one with null stuffed data points http://jsfiddle.net/4Mngx/1/), the x axis tick marks are staggered to the left of each column.

Removing the "stacked" property of the columns seems to resolve the issue, but the columns have to be stacked in order to have the appropriate thickness, otherwise the columns are made thin in order to fit all the series into each tick mark even though only one series actually has real data per tick mark.

`$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
  "title": {
    "text": "This is a title"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "7 Days (01/16/2014 - 01/22/2014)"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
      "day": "%b %e"
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Y axis title"
    },
    "min": -1,
    "max": 7
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "showInLegend": true,
      //"stacking": "stacking"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Green",
      "color": "#4CB158",
      "borderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1389848400000,
          "y": 2,
        }
      ],
      "threshold": -10
    },
    {
      "name": "Yellow",
      "color": "#FFA93C",
      "borderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
      ],
      "threshold": -10
    },
    {
      "name": "Red",
      "color": "#EA494A",
      "borderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1390280400000,
          "y": 4
        }
      ],
      "threshold": -10
    },
    {
      "name": "Grey",
      "color": "#cccccc",
      "borderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": 1389934800000,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 1390021200000,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 1390107600000,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 1390194000000,
          "y": 0
        },

        {
          "x": 1390366800000,
          "y": 0
        }
      ],
      "threshold": -10
    }
  ]
});
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your first time,

```
GMT: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 05:00:00 GMT
Your time zone: 1/16/2014 12:00:00 AM GMT-5
```

I'm assuming it's localtime not GMT and `highcharts` is shifting the label 5 hours.  If you shift your time do it's `16 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT`, the label will be centered.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mngx/3/).

**OR**

If you want to use local time adjust highcharts [global option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC).

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mngx/4/) with this option.

Comment: Mark, so highcharts defaults to GMT in their system settings or something? Yes I am creating the js timestamps with our local system time.

Comment: @billmalarky, yes exactly **and** you can even adjust this setting.  See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Mngx/4/, might work better for your situation.

Comment: Wow, this has been very helpful. I won't have time to implement this solution until Monday, but I think you've cracked it. I'll mark your answer as correct for now and re-open if I still can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.pointRange) parameter and [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval)

Other solution is using [categories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories).

Comment: Well we used categories instead of datetime for the x axis before successfully but it felt like a hack to have a date formatted category instead of using the actual datetime chart type.